# making a basketball game. what are my doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I'm making a basketball game and everything is weird I just need help knowing what I'm doing wrong! I'm so confused! here is my code pen link go check out the code https://codepen.io/cohanroderick123/pen/xxEBVRr may have to copy and paste it. plz help

```
    $red: #D83204;
body{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    background: lightBlue;
  background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3194017/bballBg.png);
    font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
    position:relative;
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#Calque_1{
    max-width: 100vw;
    max-height: 100vh;
  overflow:visible;
}

.ground{
  background: #233033;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    height: 18.5vh;
    width: 100vw;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

button{
  color: $red;
  background: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  margin-top:3vh;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border:solid grey 2px;
  transition: all ease 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline:none;
  &:hover{
    background: $red;
    color: white;
  }
}
```

Comment: Define "something's wrong"?

Comment: where do you see that?

Comment: Ah, so, nothing's wrong?

Comment: are you ok? your making no sense at all

Comment: Yeah sorry, I must be tired. I thought something was wrong with the code above.

Comment: well im confused why its not working can you tell? click on the code pen link

Comment: So when you call the doctor, you tell them "Hi doctor, I don't feel so good, what's the exact diagnostic and the medicine I should take?" If so, what do you think the doctor will reply? :) You described no problem at all. You didn't explain what's the expected behaviour, nor what's the current one, nor what are the steps to reproduce the issue, nor the debugging attempts. All we can do is guess there is... some problem? Somewhere? And provide some miracle solution? :)

Comment: @portsmouthsports plz check my answer if this what you want plz accept it

Answer (score 0):

it works fine your just missing to add the link into the body
`<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>`